# how to call a public api in Watson Assistant webhook?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am calling a public api with IBM fucntion in Watson assistant webhook.
how to call a public api without IBM fucntion?

Comment: What have you configured as the webhook. Have you tried specifying the external public webhook?

Comment: As mentioned you should be able to call out to any public REST API, as long as the returned data is in a format i.e. json / text that can then be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IBM Watson Assistant allows call-outs to webhooks in different places and for several reasons](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-overview). This can be for logging purposes, before and after processing a user message or within dialog steps. The latter could be used to gather information from external sources.

As far as I know, you can call out to external webhooks in all of the supported places.

Comment: We must return data with JSON Object. JSON Array Not Working.